# How use writeToFile in Firebase to deal with exceeds the maximum size?

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase-storage

I need help with loading the image from the Firebase Database. I have uploaded 2 images to the firebase. When I want to load the images. It appears this error

```
  Attempeted to download object with size of 1050168 bytes, which exceeds the maximum size of 1048576 bytes. Consider raising the maximum download size, or using [FIRStorageReference writeToFile:]
```

However, sometimes I could load 2 images, sometimes it stucks.

I am pretty new to Swift and Firebase.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(toDoList[indexPath.row].imageName)
    let storageRef1 = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(toDoList[indexPath.row].secondPhoto)
    let itemSelected = toDoList[indexPath.row]
    storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if let data = data
                {
                    storageRef1.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data1, error) in

                        if error == nil
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                if let data1 = data1
                                {
                                    let detailVC:DetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
                                    print(itemSelected.eventID)
                                    detailVC.eventIDfromDetail = itemSelected.eventID
                                    detailVC.titleEvent = itemSelected.title
                                    detailVC.staffEvent = itemSelected.staff
                                    detailVC.locationEvent = itemSelected.location
                                    detailVC.startEvent = itemSelected.starts
                                    detailVC.endEvent = itemSelected.ends
                                    detailVC.repeatEvent = itemSelected.rpeat
                                    detailVC.imageDetail = UIImage(data: data)!
                                    detailVC.descriptionDetail = itemSelected.description
                                    detailVC.secondPhotoEvent = UIImage(data: data1)!
                                    detailVC.key = itemSelected.key
                                    detailVC.isFinish = itemSelected.isCompleted
                                    self.presentViewController(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print(error!.localizedDescription)
                        }

                    }}
            })
        }
        else
        {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to raise the `dataWithMaxSize`. Beware, according to the Firebase docs, that you don't download a file that exceeds the device's memory capacity or the app will crash. The link to the Firebase Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files).